# Combine each element in a dictionary with a default set of parameters

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'd like to achieve a sort of "defaults" for Ansible a dictionary of dictionaries within my inventory variables.
I understand that filters may be used to achieve something along these lines, but I cannot figure out the exact incantation to make this happen.

With a single-dimension dictionary a `combine` filter can be used - is there something similar to `combine` on each of the dictionary elements? I have tried the use of `map` and `map('combine')` but this function seems to be built primarily for lists.

I have tried this both within variables for playbooks and inventory lookups - I have also tried methods using roles and default variables there, but cannot make something that feels elegant enough for production use.

Given the following variables.yaml file:

```yaml
---
example_base:
  alice:
    foo: 1
  bob:
    bar: 2


example_defaults:
  baz: 3
  foo: 0

example: >-
  {%- set result = {} -%}
  {%- for name, values in example_base.items() -%}
  {%- set _= result.update({name: example_defaults|combine(values, recursive=true)}) -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
  {{ result }}
```

I would like to combine `example_defaults` to each sub-dictionary of the `example_base` dictionary within the variables.yaml file, rather than within the playbook - this will allow me to not have to define every common variable amongst my dictionary items.

The `example` declaration works - Is there a more concise way to achieve this using Jinja/Ansible filters?

Wanted outcome:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "alice": {
            "baz": 3,
            "foo": 1
        },
        "bob": {
            "bar": 2,
            "baz": 3,
            "foo": 0
       }
}
```

An example playbook.yaml could be -

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars_files:
    - variables.yaml

  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ example }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where writing a few lines of python is probably the easiest and most sustainable over time, more specifically if you need to apply defaults in the same way to different dictionaries.

Test file structure:

```
.
├── filter_plugins
│   └── my_custom_filters.py
└── playbook.yml
```

`filter_plugins/my_custom_filters.py`

```py
def dict_defaults(input_dict, defaults):
    """apply defaults to every key of the input dict"""
    return {k: {**defaults, **v} for (k, v) in input_dict.items()}


class FilterModule(object):
    """my custom filters"""

    def filters(self):
        """Return the filter list."""
        return {
            'dict_defaults': dict_defaults
        }
```

`playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Custom filter demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    example_base: {alice: {foo: 1}, bob: {bar: 2}}
    example_defaults: {baz: 3, foo: 0}

  tasks:
    - name: Apply defaults with custom filter
      debug:
        var: example_base | dict_defaults(example_defaults)
```

Running the playbook gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [Custom filter demo] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Apply defaults with custom filter] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "example_base | dict_defaults(example_defaults)": {
        "alice": {
            "baz": 3,
            "foo": 1
        },
        "bob": {
            "bar": 2,
            "baz": 3,
            "foo": 0
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Really nice solution - thank you for pointing me in the right direction in regards to a custom filter plugins.
I wonder is there a built-in filter which might achieve the same result without having to include this albeit short custom filter?

Comment: `I wonder is there a built-in filter which might achieve the same result ` <= not to my knowledge. It's actually possible to do it the other way around with stock filter (i.e. combine values of each keys with overrides) but in your above way (i.e. override defaults with values form each key) I've always wirten either jinja2 as you did in your question or a custom filter as my above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"Is there a more concise way to achieve this using Jinja/Ansible filters?"***

A: Create the dictionary with the defaults. Use the filter [*product*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) to combine the keys and the defaults. Then [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) it with the dictionary *example_base*

```yaml
  example: "{{ dict(example_base.keys()|
                    product([example_defaults]))|
               combine(example_base, recursive=true) }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  example:
    alice:
      baz: 3
      foo: 1
    bob:
      bar: 2
      baz: 3
      foo: 0
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    example_base:
      alice:
        foo: 1
      bob:
        bar: 2

    example_defaults:
      baz: 3
      foo: 0

    example: "{{ dict(example_base.keys()|
                      product([example_defaults]))|
                 combine(example_base, recursive=true) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: example
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me a way by using built-in filters - I feel a filter plugin might be a cleaner way to handle this, but seeing this solution helped me to understand casting and the product filters.